# Component does not load upon URL change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to navigate to a sibling component, the url changes but the component does not change, it remains in the current component.  I have to refresh the app to load the component which defeats the SPA design.
I tested the same link from `Navbar` component which is also a sibling of `PlatformResult` component which works fine but does not work when tried to navigate from `StatusTable` component. I'm sure I'm doing something silly here, please help me figure out what's going on here.

As a workaround to this problem, I using event service to notify app component from status component, the app component navigates to the url and the component loads as expected. But I don't prefer this as it seems like a overkill for a simple problem

**app.component.ts**

```
  @Component({
selector: 'app',
template: `
<div class="wrapper">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <div class="content-wrapper container-fluid"> 
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" [ngStyle]="{'display': style}">{{error}}</div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
       </div>

    </div>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
`,
directives: [Navbar, Sidebar, Footer, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, DataService, NavigationService],
styleUrls: ['styles/app.css']

   @RouteConfig([{
        path: '/status',
        name: 'Home',
        component: StatusTable,
        useAsDefault: true
    }, {
            path: '/platform',
            name: 'Platform',
            component: PlatformResult
        }, {
            path: '/**',
            name: 'Other',
            redirectTo: ['Home']
        }])

export class AppComponent {
    error: string;
    showError: boolean;
    style: Object;

    constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService, private router: Router) {
        // listen to navigation events
        // AS A WORKAROUND, THIS IS THE WAY I CAN NAVIGATE TO /platform from /status
        navigationService.navigationAnnounced$.subscribe(
            message => {
                router.navigate([message.componentName, message.params]);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**status.template.html (partial)**

```
...  
<thead class="heading" [ngClass]="{'fade-table': spinner}">
        <tr>
            <th>Diffs ({{diffCount}})</th>
            <th *ngFor="#platform of platforms">
                <div class="vertical" style="width:30px">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/Platform', {name: platform.name}]">
                        <small>{{platform?.name}}<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="platform.ssl">({{platform?.ssl}})</span></small>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th><small>Assigned To</small></th>
            <th><small class="pull-left">Comments</small></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` from

```
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, DataService, NavigationService],
```

add them only to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])`

to have global instances. If you add them on the component as well the component gets a different (new) instance which breaks routing.

Comment: Aah! dang! I knew it I was doing very silly. Works now. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Glad to hear this fixed it :)

Comment: Although it fixed my main issue, it seems to have bad impact in routing in StatusTable component, any route I set in the component is triggering a full page load and goes back to home page
Ex: this function is in StatusTable , when invoked it sets the URL query parms -- this is failing now. Any clues?

ex:   goto(area, branch, date, comments) {
        this.router.navigate(['Home', this.setRouteParams(area, branch, date, comments)]);
        this.getRegressionStatus(area, branch, date, comments);
    }

Comment: I think that's a different issue. Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: I ended up solving with help from gitter chat. Here's the question. Please suggest if theres any other alternative
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320350/setting-route-params-in-child-component-reloads-the-page-and-resets

Comment: If this fixes the issue, it's the right (probably only) way.